# How to handle a async API call in gluon javafx Application

Tags: rest, javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile, gluon-desktop

How to login with a REST API server from gluon mobile application. I have tried HttpClient which does able to call .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access a REST API you can use RestClient.

```
     import com.gluonhq.connect.provider.RestClient;

     RestClient restClient = RestClient.create()
         .host("http://myhost.com")
         .path("restservice/login")
         .queryParam("username","myname")
         .queryParam("password","myencodedpassword")
         .method("GET");
     GluonObservableObject<User> sample = DataProvider.retrieveObject(restClient.createObjectDataReader(User.class));
```

To then handle the result you can use the stateProperty

```
    sample.stateProperty().addListener((obv,ov,nv)->{
         if(nv.equals(ConnectState.SUCCEEDED)){
             User loggedInUser = sample.get();
         }
    });
```

you can use initializedProperty as well.

[RestClient JavaDoc](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/3.0.0/index.html?com/gluonhq/connect/provider/RestClient.html)

Comment: what is user.class here ?

Comment: User.class is a POJO. You must provide this to match the object being returned. [Retreive Object](http://docs.gluonhq.com/connect/1.0.0/#_retrieving_an_object)

Comment: How i will use `ProgressIndicator` for background progress .

Comment: I haven't found anything for the DataProvider that gives a progress value. Use the Indeterminate progress indicator.